# HTML Footer does not stay at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I made an HTML page that includes a header, 3 columns(left, main and right) and a footer.
In the main column I have a table with a height of 100%, so pretty large. Now I want to have my footer under the table.

I do not know what is wrong but my footer is not placed at the bottom, in my case it is almost at the middle of the main table.

The html, body and main class are also set to height 100% so that is working perfect.
The only problem is the footer..

On request here is some more code:

```
<body>  
<div id="wrap">
<div id="hoofding"></div>
<div id="inner-wrap">
<div id="navigatie" style="font-family:old stamper">
  <a href="index.html" class="C1"><font size="9">Home</font></a>
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="right"></div>
<table id= "tabel1">
 <div id="inhoud">
<tr><td><p style="font-family:army of darkness"><font size="30">Lettertype 1: The Quick Brown Fox</font></p></td></tr>              
<tr><td><p style="font-family:USSR army"><font size="30">Lettertype 2: The Quick Brown Fox</font></p></td></tr>
 </div>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer"><font size="1">Copyright &copy 2013 The Pack</font></div>
 </body>
```

And the CSS file:

```
    html {height:100%; width: 100%;}

    body {
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  } 

    #hoofding{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 355px;
  width: 620px;
  background-image: url(Afbeeldingen/The%20Pack.png);
  }
    #navigatie{
      z-index: 15;
      position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 8%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
   }
#inhoud{
      z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
   }

   #tabel1{
      height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url(Afbeeldingen/Inhoud.png);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 15%;
  bottom: 0;
  padding:15px;
  }

    #wrap {
      position:relative;
      min-height:100%;
        }
    * html #wrap {height:100%; width:100%}

     #inner-wrap {
        padding-bottom:20px;
       }
     #inner-wrap:after {
       content:" ";
       display:block;
       clear:both;
        }
     #footer {
        position:absolute;
        height:18px;
        background-color: red;
        bottom:0px;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        clear:both;
          }

    #left {
      position:fixed;
      float:left;
      width:10px;
      text-align:center;
        }
    #main {
      position:absolute;
      margin-left:10px;
      margin-right:10px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
        }

   #right {
      float:right;
      width:10px;
      text-align:center;
       }
   #content {
     padding:5px;
     margin-right:10px;
     text-align:left;
       }
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you make a JsFiddle? Link [JsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I have never done this before.. But I will try. Please wait while I try to figure it out.

Comment: Fill in your HTML (Left box) and Css (Right box) and than press save.. you can copy the url and paste it here

Comment: Try removing the z-index: 1; for #table1

Comment: I made a JsFiddle file and removed all the unnecessary things like header, left and right column. And then my conclusion was that it worked on that ?programm? So I went back to my HTML document to see if I was wrong but no, it does not work on my HTML page but is does work on the JsFiddle file.. How is this possible? Is it because I removed too much?

Comment: @Gimmy I tried but that does not seem to work?

Comment: @user2475152 yes i think you have deleted to much..

Comment: @CTravel but if I copy my whole code it says that there are things I do not need. And I'm using an image as header so that isn't possible to add in the JsFiddle file.

Comment: show more of your code!!!

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ Have you tried this @user2475152?

Comment: @parzival Yes I tried but it still does not work

Comment: @user2475152 here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/DQNyF/2/. you might have to clean up other css properties though.

Comment: @parzival so if I make the table with the text larger it should still work?

Comment: It should. Font size shouldn't make any difference. Just clean up your css a bit. :)

Comment: I have made a few changes to the html too. See if it matches with your code.

Comment: @parzival yes I see, it works fine for now, but I posted another question before this one to ask how I can put the height of the table at 100%, if I do what they told me to do then it does not work.. The table height still stays the same.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This does not work, it just made it worse.. Now the footer is placed at the bottom of the screen and when I scroll it moves up.. And also the text is positioned at the left not in the center.

Comment: now check it out! an btw did not you wanted it to stick at the bottom?

Comment: That doesn't work either.. And yeah I wanted it at the bottom but at the bottom of the page not of the screen. Where my screen stops there is the footer placed, but my page is longer so I have to scroll down to see the end of the page and that is were I want my footer.

Comment: Then please paste your HTML as well without that we cannot do anything!

Comment: I did it if you want the CSS file just ask. I only pasted the body, the head is not important.

Comment: Done, sorry if it is a lot but you wanted all.. I'm not a pro so mind the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
bottom: 0;
```

rather than

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

i think it will work for you.